# Abstract Factory implementation error

Tags: c#, design-patterns, ado.net

I want to implement Abstract Factory pattern to maximize code efficiency to read my coımmon reference types. To achieve this I have the following implementations

[image]

and to implement the pattern I have implemented the following:

[image]

My code for the ***RefEntityFactor*** class is :

```
public class RefEntityFactory<T> : IRefEntityFactory<T> where T : IRefEntity
{
    public List<T> Search(string sp_name, int? id, string code, int? statusid)
    {
        List<T> irefs = new List<T>();
        string procName = sp_name;
        SqlConnection conn = null;

        using (conn = GetConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procName, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (id.HasValue)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id.Value);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", code.Trim());
            if (statusid.HasValue)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", statusid.Value);

            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                RefEntity refe = new RefEntity();
                refe.Id = int.Parse(rd["ID"].ToString());
                refe.Code = rd["CODE"].ToString();
                refe.Status = short.Parse(rd["STATUS"].ToString());
                IRefEntity iref = (IRefEntity)refe;

                irefs.Add((T)iref);    // Exception will be THROWN HERE!!!!
            }
            rd.Close();
        }
        return irefs;
    }
}
```

Then I implement a class for spesific type:

[image]

as

```
public static List<IPaymentType> SearchPaymentTypes(int? id, string code, int? statusid)
    {
        RefEntityFactory<IPaymentType> fact = new RefEntityFactory<IPaymentType>();

        return fact.Search(@"[dbo].[SEARCH_PAYMENTTYPES]", id, code, statusid);
    }
```

But obviously when I run the code it throws an exception at the line where I mark as comment.

How can I correct my implementation?

Regards.

Comment: Shouldn't you method return a `List<IRefentiy>` rather than an `List<T>`, Your code is trying to cast a `RefEntity` to a `T` so if `T` is more derived than `RefEntity` then it will fail. You can also just do `IRefEntity iref = new RefEntity();` and remove `refe` entirely.

Comment: is it a divison by zero exception or a file not found exception?

Comment: @BenRobinson : When I convert the return type to List<IRefEntity> rather than List<T> I can not write the SearchPaymentTypes method. The return type will be collection of IRefEntity which I require to return collection of IPaymentType and list.ForEach(x => (IPaymentType)x); will not work.

Comment: @WeylandYutani: I am getting an Exception caused by type conversions. Any other Exception type is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, this will be because `RefEntity` isn't of type `T`, have you tried taking the approach by constructing the new `T`, so something like this in your while loop:

```
T refe = new T();
refe.Id = int.Parse(rd["ID"].ToString());
refe.Code = rd["CODE"].ToString();
refe.Status = short.Parse(rd["STATUS"].ToString());

irefs.Add(ref);
```

You'll also need to extend your [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to limit your `T` to require a parameterless constructor as well, so something like:

```
public class RefEntityFactory<T> : IRefEntityFactory<T> where T : IRefEntity, new()
```

also you should change the **SearchPaymentTypes** as follows to make it work:

```
public static List<IPaymentType> SearchPaymentTypes(int? id, string code, int? statusid)
    {
        RefEntityFactory<PaymentType> fact = new RefEntityFactory<PaymentType>();
        List<PaymentType> list = fact.Search(@"[dbo].[SEARCH_PAYMENTTYPES]", id, code, description, statusid);

        return list.Select(x => (IPaymentType)x).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: When  I do the changes you suggest I get the following error: 

*'Interfaces.IPaymentType' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'RefEntityFactory<T>'* in the **SearchPaymentTypes** method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the RefEntityFactory creates RefEntity objects. RefEntitys cannot be cast to IPaymentType because they don't implement IPaymentType.

You don't need to use generic parameters to implement the abstract factory pattern. The abstract factory's method can return IRefEntity:

```
interface IRefEntityFactory
{
    List<IRefEntity> Search(string sp_name, int? id, string code, int? statusid);
}
```

and concrete factories would return the various concrete entity types that implement IRefEntity:

```
class PayrollEntityFactory : IRefEntityFactory
{
    public List<IRefEntity> Search(string sp_name, int? id, string code, int? statusid)
    {
        List<IRefEntity> ret = new List<IRefEntity>();
        ret.Add(new PaymentType());
        return ret;
    }
}
```

or

```
class NnnnEntityFactory : IRefEntityFactory
{
    public List<IRefEntity> Search(string sp_name, int? id, string code, int? statusid)
    {
        List<IRefEntity> ret = new List<IRefEntity>();
        ret.Add(new NnnnType());
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Or the abstract factory could be an abstract class instead of an interface. That would allow common code to be shared by all implementations and avoid duplication of much of eg the SQL queries. But the actual concrete object (eg payroll) creation cannot be shared, each object's construction will need to be unique.